# Detect shadowed java bean property

Tags: java, inheritance, recursion, javabeans, introspection

Is there an easy way (idealy existing helper library) to detect shadowed attributes of a java bean given it has multiple level of hierarchy?

[C] extends [B] extends [A].
Then attribute [A].firstName is defined.

I want to detect beans where [C].firstName is redefined (which is likely a developer error) inside a generic jUnit test so this kind of "hard to find bug" is catched by the build process.

Note: in Eclispe IDE this is equivalent to "Field declaration hides another field or variable" under Java/Compiler/Errors/Name shadowing and conflicts.

Comment: best way to avoid this is not to inherit. Rather you should declare inheritance hierarchy through interfaces and compose the implementation with instances of the "lower" hierarchy layers.

Comment: detecting such problems is not a task for a UnitTest. UnitTests check behavior of the code. Inheritance is no behavior. The right tool to detect this would be _findbugs_ or _pmd_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically you wouldn't put this in a unit test, rather you'd put something like [Checkstyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/) in your integration build process which will flag the same issue.

Comment: _checkstyle_ may not get this, _findbugs_ or _pmd_ would be better.

Comment: Checkstyle does have `HiddenFieldCheck` which looks like it should work, but I agree findbugs is a great thing to run too :)